# Ошибка Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)')) Python Requests

Tags: python, requests, ssl

Делаю парсер на Python requests с использованием прокси. Когда передаю только http параметр - всё работает, но если передаю и http, и https - получаю ошибку

```
Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)'))
```

Вот код:

```
session = requests.session()
proxy_auth = HTTPProxyAuth("login", "password")

with open("user-agent.txt") as user_agent_file:
    user_agent = eval(user_agent_file.read())
get_headers = {'user-agent': choice(user_agent)}

with open("proxy_list.txt") as proxy_list_file:
    proxy_list = proxy_list_file.read().strip().split('\n')
proxy = {'https': f'https://{proxy_list[0]}', 'http': f'http://{proxy_list[0]}'}

ip_checker = session.get('http://icanhazip.com', headers = get_headers, proxies = proxy, auth = proxy_auth, verify = False).text
print(ip_checker)

sleep(uniform(1,2))
session.cookies.clear()
html = session.get(f'https://www.avito.ru/rossiya/avtomobili/bmw?cd=1&p={i}', headers = get_headers, proxies = proxy, auth = proxy_auth, verify = False).text
```

Проверяю запрос на http://icanhazip.com - ошибок нет, принт выводит айпи прокси. Следующий запрос делаю на сайт, который нужно парсить - ловлю ошибку. Прокси платные, с сайта https://proxy6.net/en. verify = False никаким образом не сказывается на результате. В чём может быть дело и как решить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогло изменение параметра proxy с

```
{'https': f'https://{proxy_list[0]}', 'http': f'http://{proxy_list[0]}'}
```

на

```
{'https': f'http://{proxy_list[0]}', 'http': f'http://{proxy_list[0]}'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution helped me:

```
conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as sess:
    ...
```

Read more here:
https://aiohttp-kxepal-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#ssl-control-for-tcp-sockets

Comment: на этом сайте принято общаться по-русски.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло:

```
pip3 install urllib3==1.25
```